# How to use nUnit Tests in WinRT application?

Tags: c#, nunit, winrt-async

I don't know how to use nUnit in WinRT applications(metro).
I write this code and run test (using Resharper test runner).
The test was passed. Why?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace UnitTestInWinRT
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NUnitClassTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestnUnitAsyncTest()
        {
            var number = GetNumberAsync(7);
            number.ContinueWith(n => Assert.AreEqual("string is 6", n.Result));
        }
        public Task<string> GetNumberAsync(int n)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => "string is " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is:

You use [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) method.

> Ceates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes.

So, NUnit runs your lamba in other thread, and ends test method. `AssertionExcecption` occures in other thread, that's why test is passed.

If you ran it in the same thread, test will fail as expected.

```
[TestFixture]
public class NUnitClassTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestnUnitAsyncTest()
    {
        var number = GetNumberAsync(7);
        number.Wait();
        Assert.AreEqual("string is 6", number.Result);
    }

    public Task<string> GetNumberAsync(int n)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => "string is " + n);
    }
}
```